# Find the generating function for this recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $S_n$ be the number of positive integer roots of the equation $x+2y+3z =n$

Find the generating function of $S_n+S_{n+1}+S_{n+2}$, $(n\geq 6)$

---

Surely the generating function of $S_n$ is $f(x) = {{x^6} \over {(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}}$

Let $g(x)$ be the generating function of $S_n+S_{n+1}+S_{n+2}$, $(n\geq 6)$

[I.e. $g(x) =(S_6 + S_7 + S_8)x^6 + (S_7 + S_8 + S_9)x^7 + (S_8 + S_9 + S_10)x^8+...$ ]

$f(x) = S_6 x^6 + S_7x^7 + S_8x^8 + ...$

$xf(x) = S_6 x^7 + S_7x^8 + S_8x^9 + ...$

$x^2 f(x) = S_6 x^8 + S_7x^9 + S_8x^{10} + ...$

Hence $(1+x+x^2)f(x) = S_6x^6 + (S_6+S_7)x^7 +x^2g(x) $

Therefore, $g(x) = (1+ {1\over x} + {1 \over x^2})f(x) - S_6 x^4 - (S_6 + S_7)x^5$

In my lecturer's note, he claimed $g(x) = (1+ {1\over x} + {1 \over x^2})f(x)$.

What the point did I have a mistake? I can't find which point I was wrong.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since you only care about when $n \ge 6$, both answers are equivalent in that sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion arises because it is not clear how $T_n = S_n + S_{n+1} + S_{n+2}$ should be defined for $n < 6$.  We have two choices:  either we can choose $T_n = 0$ for any integer $n < 6$, or we can choose $S_n = 0$ for any integer $n < 6$, thus $$T_n = \begin{cases} 0, & n \le 3 \\ S_6, & n = 4 \\ S_6 + S_7, & n = 5 \\ S_n + S_{n+1} + S_{n+2}, & n \ge 6. \end{cases}$$  This second definition is the one I prefer, because it is not as if $S_5$ is undefined under the interpretation of $S_n$.  There are exactly $0$ positive integer solutions to $x + 2y + 3z = 5$.  Consequently, we are not justified to say $T_n = 0$ if $n < 6$.

If you use the first interpretation, then your derivation is correct.  If you use the second interpretation, then $$g(x) = (1 + x^{-1} + x^{-2})f(x)$$ is correct.  It is easy to see why if we write

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty S_n x^n,$$ where $S_n = 0$ when $n < 6$.  Then this gives us $$\frac{f(x)}{x} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty S_{n+1} x^n, \quad \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty S_{n+2} x^n.$$  Therefore $$(1 + x^{-1} + x^{-2})f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (S_n + S_{n+1} + S_{n+2}) x^n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty T_n x^n = g(x).$$